# Transforms moving around the 3D cursor?

Tags: transforms, 3d-cursor

I think I accidentally pressed something to make it like this:

[image]

See how the XYZ arrows are at the 3D cursor instead of those vertexes I've selected?

How do I fix that? Whenever I select on a vertex or something, those blue, red, green arrows would always be where I selected, now it just keeps going to the 3D cursor.

Comment: It looks like you pressed `.` (period), which sets the pivot point to the 3D cursor. You can press `,` (comma) to set it to bounding box, and `Ctrl+,` to set it to median (the default).

Answer (score 12):

[image]

Pivot point is a very important thing to learn. Also, yes, median is what you are looking for.