# Uses of the 3D Cursor

Tags: 3d-cursor

I know the 3D Cursor can be used to position new objects, or snap existing ones to a certain location - but what else can it be used for?

An **exhaustive list of every possible use** would be great (without repeating similar things like "pivot for spin tool", "pivot for screw tool" - which could simply be said as "Pivot for modeling tools").

Answer (score 6):

Below are some uses of the 3d cursor in Blender with examples

- Precise placement of new objects
- Pivot for transformations, example - [Transforms moving around the 3D cursor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8604/12)
- Pivot for modeling tools and modifiers (e.g. mirror, spin, screw...)
- Moving the origin of objects (<kbd>Ctrl-Alt-Shift-C</kbd>), example - [Change pivot or local origin of an object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1291/12)
- A visual placeholder, for example to remember where something was previously in an animation.
- Accurate relocation of objects/relocating objects to exactly the same place
- Source location for the Clone Brush Tool (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> to set).

Comment: There are existing questions on the site with some of these as answers, if anyone reading this can find any, please add them.

Comment: Sometimes I use the 3D cursor as a place marker for animations (e.g. the foot is at the 3d cursor on this frame)

Comment: I suppose that counts, added it.

Comment: There's a clone brush tool? Neat! (:

Comment: What is the new shortcut of CTRL ALT SHIFT C in blender 2.80 2.81 2.82 2.83 ??? beceause it look like it is removed definetivly..