# how to place circle in a far location from centre

Tags: 3d-view

[image: circle]

A certain doubt always looms, when this circle is clicked ( by default ), it always remains near the screen. I mean with a click at most the cursor goes a bit away but not far from it. How does one get to place it lets say 20 measuring units ( inches or meters ) away.

Because it is in 3d space, this cursor should diminish in size as it goes far. That is my notion. could somebody clarify this.

Comment: Here you go: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24787/uses-of-the-3d-cursor

Comment: You can type in the desired x.y.z components of the 3d cursor by using the 3D cursor panel in the `N` toolshelf in 3D View - This is by far the best way to control the 3D cursor with precision.

Comment: [Precisely move the 3D cursor](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/13829/2217)