# Navigating viewports in Blender for beginner

Tags: 3d-view

Hi so I have just installed my blender software on windows. I have just finished watching how to navigate viewports, and this is where I'm stuck unfortunately :D 
Yes, I am a noob at this, I am very familiar with GIS software but not this. 
So to say, when watching the tutorial on navigating viewports I see that the guy can easly zoom, pan and rotate the view with only using his mouse and his left and middle button. What happens when I click the left m-button is I only shift the place of a white and red circle with a black cross in it. see picture here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EIjb5COfmdECQwwo_jPxEMNYRozDHa4g

This is very annoying, I want to be able to pan and rotate to move around in 3d space when I use left m-button. 
And what is this marker for actually?

Sincerly thanks
P

Comment: maybe the [Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/navigate/navigation.html) helps

Comment: Please read the manual and watch some videos on how to use the interface. The left button is to move the 3d cursor, the middle button and scroll wheel will allow you to navigate, the right mouse button is to select and objects.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24787/uses-of-the-3d-cursor

Answer (score 1):

If you like:
1. [Download this file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RgJt31i67mLgTVsp8xrqLxplpoEK9RBr)

2. open blender. Press CTRL+ALT+U (File>User preferences>Input)
3. At the bottom of the window there's a button: "Import Key Configuration".
4. Point to the file you downloaded on (1).

Alternatively: Customize your mouse PAN, ZOOM, DOLLY. Go to CTRL+ALT+U (File-User Preferences)
Go to Input tab. Unfold "3D view", find "zoom view" - mouse - Wheel In. If there is not such command create a new one using those options:
[image: mouse wheel zooms in/out]

To use the Middle Mouse button (MMB) to Rotate around the view and move (drag) etc... check this out;
[image: Change mouse manipulation for viewport]
The cursor is deactivated. It will *TOTALLY* get in your way now that you´re beginning to use the software.

Comment: My advise for beginners is to learn blender using the default settings. Customizing shortcuts and navigation will make it harder to follow tutorials and getting help.

Comment: If placing 3D cursor gets in the way then it isn't used correctly. How will it be placed with this configuration?

Comment: The 3d cursor gets in the way of a new commer. Once he´s experienced he can reset blender back to defaults. The objective of early customization in blender is not to loose interest or get disappointed with first try-it-yourself experimentations. Steep curve I heard last time on a bConf.

Comment: The kids in my classes never had problems with that. But they had a proper introduction. What I switch though is MMB and Shift MMB